# Is there any evidence to support a correlation between how much bodily energy you are using, and how quickly time appears to pass?

Tags: perception, time, physiology

It seems to me that time passes more slowly when I am drinking coffee, but when I stop, or I am tired it seems that time passes a lot faster.

Could this have something to do with the sampling rate at which the life-loop in my brain can perceive things?  Since a higher sampling rate in this life-loop would cause more time to be perceived?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's literature on temporal expansion with vigilance.  Perhaps this might get you started.

Tse, P. U., Intriligator, J., Rivest, J., and Cavanagh, P. (2004). Attention and the subjective expansion of time. *Perception & Psychophysics*, *66*(7):1171–1189.

In this instance they're looking at how odd, unique, or surprising events might increase the amount of attention applied and that those events seem to last longer than othewise very comparable ones.  The literature reviews speaks a bit to what you've asked about.